# Ballerina: extraneous input 'S' expecting {<EOF>, '','','',''} error appear once read a config using ballerina/config

Tags: ballerina

The following error appears once I read a config file using ballerina/config. The error is not descriptive enough to correct the issue.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add double quotes for the string type config values.

eg:
ballerina code

```
string x =  config:getAsString("XVAL");
```

conf file content

```
XVAL="1S"
```

Comment: It's really great if it is possible to improve the error details. For aforementioned scenario error should be as follows

Error - Config file read error FileName [FileName] Line[Line No]

Comment: You can report a git issue at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues for this.

Comment: "extraneous input" error will show even when we haven't defined RHS values in ballerina.conf.